# How to show arrow images in center?

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

In my app I have one layout to show text on top, image in center and then text in bottom. But now I want to try add Images of left arrow on left side and right arrow on right side in center of the image layout. Because I am using swipe in activity.

Following is my xml code and what I have tried. I want to use weight if it is possible.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/light" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

/////////////////////////I have tried this   


    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left" 
        android:background="@drawable/left"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right" 
        android:background="@drawable/right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

///////////////////////////////////////

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_space"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".5" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.info.abc.TextViewEx
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="@dimen/betxt"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thank u all for your quick response.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct which helped you so that others can come to know about the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/left"/>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/yourimage"/>


    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/right"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

OR

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/left" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/yourimage" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/right" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a RelativeLayout for your need.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with Using  `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your `LinearLayout` with the `RelativeLayout` and made its gravity to `center` and set the images to left and right and it done.

Just change your layout `android:id="@+id/layout2"` with `RelativeLayout` as below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/left" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/right" />
    </RelativeLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Relative layout like:-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yourTextItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             >
        </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

layout design using weight

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="gaesh"
        android:textColor="#4FFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center|left"
            android:src="@drawable/yout image  "
            android:background="#123456" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:src="@drawable/yout image  "
            android:background="#334343" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:src="@drawable/yout image  "
            android:background="#654321" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.info.abc.TextViewEx
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```